# Why does re-using this function not work?

Tags: functions, hooks

I have a function that adds a class based on various statements, certain pages, cpt's you're on etc.

I put this function in various sections within the page for styling purposes using `<?php is_service_class() ?>`

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this but it kind of works however, i'm just wondering why it only works **once**?  I'm trying to learn about functions and the rights and wrongs.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_service_class' ) ) {

function is_service_class () {


    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_personal' ) ) { 

        function is_personal() {
            return ( is_post_type_archive('pk-personal') || is_singular( 'pk-personal' ) || is_page( array( 6814, 'personal-family', 'Personal & Family Services' ) ) ) ? true : false ;

        }

        if ( is_personal() ) {
            echo 'personal-service'; 
        } 

    }

    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_business' ) ) {

        function is_business() {
            return ( is_post_type_archive('pk-business')  || is_singular( 'pk-business' ) || is_page( array( 6821, 'business-services', 'Business Services' ) ) ) ? true : false ;

        }

        if ( is_business() ) {
            echo 'business-service'; 
        } 

    }


}
}
```

Comment: This is a generic PHP question, and as such is considered off-topic for our site. That said, your logic which actually prints things is enclosed in `if` statements such that it only runs if certain functions have not yet been defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function "works" once because **before** first call of `is_service_class()`, function `is_personal` not exists and whole this block is executed

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_personal' ) ) { 
    // declaration and use of function
}
```

In next call of `is_service_class()` `is_personal` is declared and the entire block is skipped. Inside the condition `if ( !function_exists( 'is_personal' ) )` leave only the declaration:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'is_personal' ) ) { 

    function is_personal() {
        return ( is_post_type_archive('pk-personal') || is_singular( 'pk-personal' ) || is_page( array( 6814, 'personal-family', 'Personal & Family Services' ) ) ) ? true : false ;
    }
}
if ( is_personal() ) {
    echo 'personal-service'; 
}
```

Similary is with `is_business()`.

---

I would suggest this form:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'is_service_class' ) ) {

    function is_service_class () {

        if ( is_personal() ) {
            echo 'personal-service'; 
        } 
        if ( is_business() ) {
            echo 'business-service'; 
        } 
    }
}

if ( !function_exists( 'is_personal' ) ) { 

    function is_personal() {
        return ( is_post_type_archive('pk-personal') || is_singular( 'pk-personal' ) 
            || is_page( array( 6814, 'personal-family', 'Personal & Family Services' ) ) ) ? true : false ;
    }
}
if ( !function_exists( 'is_business' ) ) {

    function is_business() {
        return ( is_post_type_archive('pk-business')  || is_singular( 'pk-business' ) 
            || is_page( array( 6821, 'business-services', 'Business Services' ) ) ) ? true : false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense... i think. Overall would this be the best way of doing something like this or would another way be better?

Comment: @user4630   I do not see any sense in using nested functions. I would choose: 
`function is_service_class () {
        if ( is_personal() ) 
            echo 'personal-service'; 
        else if ( is_business() ) 
            echo 'business-service'; 
}`